# Get Redis keys filtered by Set values

Tags: redis

Let's say, I have 5000 Users. Each user can have multiple Values (count up to 500).

Like,

```
user_1 has values (1,3,5,100,250,1000)
user_3 has values (5,30,75,200,3502,1340)
user_4 has values (100,300,750,2000,3502,13400)
```

Now for query, I have a list of users (1,2,3,4,5,6,10) and values (5,10,20)

How can I filter users (1,2,3,4,5,6,10) who have any of these values (5,10,20).

From the above example. I will get users `1 & 3`

Comment: How are you storing this information? Lists, Hashes, Set...?

Comment: Looks like Sets @mattfreake

Answer (score 2):

Redis does not provide search-by-value capabilities out of the box. I suggest you look at the indexing patterns in https://redis.io/topics/indexes or try something like https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch.